# Google Client API Logger

Tags: php, logging, laravel-4, google-api-php-client

How can I use Google Client API library for PHP to log each and every HTTP request and response in a file?

The default settings for Google_Config is

```
'logger_class'  => 'Google_Logger_Null',
```

and I think I need to use `Google_Logger_File` that is configured as

```
'Google_Logger_File' => array(
      'file' => 'php://stdout',
      'mode' => 0640,
      'lock' => false,
),
```

How does `Google_Config` is used in the Google Client API?
Does `Google_Config` automatically initialize new instances from it?
How can I configure Google_Logger_File to set a file path to collect all logs?

Comment: Did you solved it? I passed the logger but I'm only getting the "request" (or a for of it)